# Acentuação no EditText

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, phpmyadmin

Tenho uma aplicação API 28 que consome WebService e envia dados por `GET` utilizando `Json`, e preciso de um campo `EditText` que aceite Acentos, mas quando chega no banco de dados ele só grava até uma letra antes do 1º acento.

• Estrutura do banco PhpMyAdmin:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

• Um registro inserido, coloquei o nome: açai. ele grava apenas a letra a.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu `Layout` onde está o `EditText` onde insiro o registro:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Deixe seu Comentário:"
            android:textColor="#548ddf"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

<!-- Meu EditText -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_Mensagem_sat_email"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="#d8d6d3"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:hint="Comente aqui"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="6"
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_satisfacao_cancela"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/botaoconsultar"
            android:text="Cancelar"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_satisfacao_enviar"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/botaoconsultar"
            android:text="Enviar"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Meu Método de envio:

```
private void inserirWEBService() {

    String url = "http://www.meusite.com.br/pasta/insereAvalia.php?linha=" + vCidade + "&horario=" + vHorario + "&sentido=" + vSentido + "&satisfacao=" + vSatisfacao + "&mensagem=" + vMensagemSatEmail;
    url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
    jsonObjectReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, this, this);
    request.add(jsonObjectReq);
}
```

Aqui meu arquivo PHP de envio:

```
<?php
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
include "conexao.php";

$jason = array();

if(isset($_GET["linha"]) && isset($_GET["horario"]) && isset($_GET["sentido"]) && isset($_GET["satisfacao"]) && isset($_GET["mensagem"]) ){

    $linha = $_GET["linha"];
    $horario = $_GET["horario"];
    $sentido = $_GET["sentido"];
    $satisfacao = $_GET["satisfacao"];
    $mensagem = $_GET["mensagem"];

    $inserir = "INSERT INTO avalieviagem (linha, horario, sentido, satisfacao, mensagem) 
                VALUES ('{$linha}', '{$horario}', '{$sentido}', '{$satisfacao}', '{$mensagem}')";

    $resultado_inserir = mysqli_query($conexao, $inserir);
}

?>
```

E o meu Encoding está como UTF-8 lá em baixo no android studio. não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: O seu problema provavelmente acontece porque a URL não está escapada. Mas eu refatoraria esse código para fazer essa requisição via POST e os dados como JSON no corpo da requisição.

Comment: Como faria isso?

Comment: @LeonardoLima foi isso mesmo, fiz a requisição via POST e deu certo, como fecho o chamado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver esse problema com a seguinte solução:

Tinha esse trecho de código:
Método que iniciava o processo.

```
private void inserirWEBService() {

    String url = "http://www.meusite.com.br/pasta/insereAvalia.php?linha=" + vCidade + "&horario=" + vHorario + "&sentido=" + vSentido + "&satisfacao=" + vSatisfacao + "&mensagem=" + vMensagemSatEmail;
    url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
    jsonObjectReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, this, this);
    request.add(jsonObjectReq);
}
```

que fazia a requisição via GET

Então mudei para requisição via POST, segue código abaixo:

```
String url = "http://www.meusite.com.br/pasta/insereAvalia.php";

            stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    if (response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("registra")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Registrado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Log.i("RESPOSTA: ", "" + response);
                    }

                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Erro ao Registrar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                    Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<>();
                    parametros.put("linha", vCidade);
                    parametros.put("horario", vHorario);
                    parametros.put("sentido", vSentido);
                    parametros.put("satisfacao", vSatisfacao);
                    parametros.put("mensagem", vMensagemSatEmail);

                    return parametros;
                }

            };
            request.add(stringRequest);
```